# C# bool method shows error

Tags: c#, user-interface

```
public bool Example_bool (bool state)
{
    if (x == state)
    {
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

why is it showing an Error? I want to deactivate a button if a certain condition runs and if not it should enable the button.

Comment: You're not returning any value, so that's probably the error. Does it really need to return anything if the point is just to deactivate the button?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad okay thanks

Comment: *showing an Error* is not a problem description unless you include information on what *Error* it's *showing*. We can't see your screen from where we're sitting. Please keep that in mind when asking future questions here.

Answer (score 4):

You have a method that expects to return a `bool` and this method doesn't return anything. If you replace `bool` with `void`, the error would disappear.

```
public void Example_bool (bool state)
{
    if (x == state)
    {
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Or more compact:

```
public void Example_bool (bool state)
{
    button.Enabled = x != state;
}
```

Comment: @Rufus L exactly ! Thanks :)

Answer (score -3):

Look at your statement. 
1. What is x where is it defined?
2. Since you are passing bool, why not to simplify like that?

```
public void Example_bool (bool state)
{

        button.Enabled = state;

}
```

Comment: Down votes are likely because you've changed the functionality of the method completely and you haven't answered the question.